# react-native project broken after react-native-git-upgrade

Tags: react-native

My packager has the following problem. [image: no idea what is going on here]

The project was working fine before I committed everything in the working tree and running react-native-git-upgrade

Running react-native-git-upgrade again gives me the following error
[image]

Comment: for me helped removing node_modules folder, then `npm i` and then `rnpm link`

Comment: Thank you. I've tried that. No luck.

Comment: try to run  react-native-git-upgrade again and see if it has errors

Comment: yes. there is an error. I will update the question above ...

Comment: so attach it to your question

Comment: You might need to upgrade your react version as well as react-native.

Comment: shouldn't this be updated by the react-native-git-upgrade command as well? the documentation doesn't say anything about how I would update react

Comment: Try to uninstall the react native maps plugin, then run react git upgrade, and then install the react maps again

Comment: thank you Cherniv. the project is working again but I cannot say for sure that it was the react-native-maps plugin